# Drag delay on Mac + Trackball

Tags: mac, selection, drag-and-drop

I use a Kensington Slimblade trackball with macOS Sierra.  I'm noticing a weird glitch where the system never seems to begin a drag where I'm initially clicking.  This problem runs throughout my applications, from selecting within images in Photoshop to dragging over text in the terminal.

If I move the cursor carefully over text, click, wait... then drag, it works fine.  But if I'm moving quickly, the mouseDown() event seems to happen at least 100ms too late.

Eg. in this text: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ, selecting from the beginning at full speed doesn't catch until the letter J.  If I select slowly, it catches around B or C.  Going annoyingly slowly will catch from the A.  If I try to drag a window over to the side, often the window won't even move unless I do it slowly, as if the window never received the initial click to initiate a drag.  This issue seems to be getting worse.

I'm running on a 4ghz Core i7 with a SSD with CPU / HD usage at a minimum.

Why is this happening and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this (on Expert Mouse 2.01) by first Resetting Defaults in Preferences as suggested, then adding my preferences back one by one.  **Turned out the one that causes this issue is the action assignment for the two lower buttons**, which I had assigned to "Drag".  Leaving this assignment out makes dragging and left clicking "hook" the position much faster.

I guess Kensington implemented a small delay to see whether you were going to click both left and right lower buttons and only when this delay times out do they interpret it as a lower-left-click only. I can understand why this is necessary but I think we should be able to tweak it.

Comment: In fact, as is logical, *any* assignment to the two lower buttons causes this.

Answer (score 1):

Aha, I did a "Restore Defaults" on the TrackballWorks preference pane and it corrected this issue.  I did the same thing on my other mac that's had this issue and it resolved the problem there too.  Solved!